# click to deploy Hadoop on GCE not working

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying "Click-to-deploy Hadoop on Google Compute Engine" [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/hadoop/click-to-deploy)

Unfortunately this doesn't seems to work : either the process stops almost immediately, or it's like it's frozen.

message displayed is

> Deployment may take 3 to 10 minutes to complete, depending on the size of your cluster 
>   Creating deployment

In any case, I can't have any cluster. Tried several zones, Hadoop versions, nothing.

Any thought ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is occurring because your Cloud project does not have a project id associated with it, but only a project number, which is true for some long-standing Cloud projects.

https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#projectnumber

You can fix this by going into **Developers Console**, selecting your project from the project list, selecting **Billing & settings** from the left-hand navigation, and adding the project id there.

The following URL should take you there directly:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/settings

Thanks,

-Matt

Comment: sorry about forgetting to answer, this is **perfectly** working (and wasn't obvious (but I should have seen these `--project=<projectid>` in cmd)

Thanks a lot Matt !

Answer (score 0):

A few items to help diagnose the problem:

Go to the Compute Engine instance list and check if there are any instances created for the deployment.

Check if there are any errors raised to the Javascript Console for your browser.
BTW, what browser and version are you using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No instance deployed (however I can (and had) deployed compute engine VM instances)

I have a 404 in console :
POST https://console.developers.google.com/m/deploy?pid=1090158225078&cmd=custom…ion=europe-west1&app=hadoop&xsrf=R5Ezthkrr1L8xU1STye3sXUiHiA:1414055456964 404 (Not Found)

on Chrome, Windows7

I tried on Firefox too : no 404 in console but same effect : no deployment at all.

Answer (score 0):

The "customdeploy" command should not be returning a 404, so let's check if there's something going on with your Cloud project.

Click to Deploy uses the preview version of [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/overview) on the backend.  Let's check the objects (if any) that Deployment Manager has created for the Hadoop deployment.

To do this, you will need to:

1. Install the Google Cloud SDK (if you have not already)
2. Add the preview component
3. Query for Deployment Manager templates
4. Query for Deployment Manager deployments

**Install the Google Cloud SDK:**

Instructions are here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

**Add the preview component:**

```
gcloud components update preview
```

**Query for Deployment Manager templates**

```
gcloud preview --project=<projectid> deployment-manager templates list
```

**Query for Deployment Manager deployments**

```
gcloud preview --project=<projectid> deployment-manager deployments --region europe-west1 list
```

One last question.  Is this a relatively "new" or "old" Google Cloud project?  Sometimes old projects need a feature to be enabled that is automatically enabled on new projects.

Thanks.